# Istanbul code coverage for Mocha tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, istanbul

I am trying to get Istanbul to work.

I keep getting this message at the end of running istanbul:

> No coverage information was collected, exit without writing coverage
>   information

I have tried everything I could find online as you can see:

```
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node ./bin/start.js",
        "test": "mocha test --no-timeouts",
        "debug_mocha": "node-debug --no-timeouts _mocha",
        "eslint": "eslint .",
        "jshint": "jshint --exclude ./node_modules .",
        "istanbul": "istanbul cover --include-all-sources --hook-run-in-context node_modules/.bin/_mocha -- -u exports -R spec test/**/*",
        "istanbul2":"istanbul cover node_modules/.bin/_mocha -- -u exports -R spec test/**/*",
        "istanbul1":"istanbul cover node_modules/.bin/_mocha -- test/**/*",
        "istanbul0":"istanbul cover _mocha test/**/*.js",
        "istanbul3":"istanbul cover _mocha -- -R spec --recursive test"
      }
```

my .istanbul.yml file is at the root of the project and looks like istanbul is picking it up successfully.

```
//.istanbul.yml
    instrumentation:
      compact: false
      save-baseline: true
    reporting:
      reports:
        - lcov
        - cobertura
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you share the code under test and the specs use to test them?

Comment: Hi JME..sorry what do you mean specs used to test them?

Comment: i see, just picking in the lingo here

Comment: Having the same issue and none of the tips out there seemed to work.

Comment: @AlexMills did you figure this out?

Comment: nah, but it's been so long, I haven't tried it, I gave up

Comment: someone on my team probably knows how this works, I will report back soon

Comment: I just started a bounty...

Comment: 11 days ago: https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/369 same problem.  Surprised nobody chimes in with an answer.

Comment: @AlexMills could you accept an answer for this one?

Comment: Hi Ben, np, I actually never verified which answer is correct; I got istanbul working on windows with mocha but never on a mac/*nix. In your answer, do you specify the actual test file? Looks like the actual test file is missing in your command?

Comment: @AlexMills yeah, no test file looks like...was a while back so I don't recall all the details.  I think the problem I was trying to solve was running any test file at all, in Windows, because Istanbul was returning no results and no coverage reports.  Fair enough if you want to wait especially if untested! :)

Answer (score 7):

Got it, finally.

https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/44#issuecomment-57708358 says:

> Using _mocha directly does not work on windows. Please use the full path to the JS file instead

Then, after a little experimentation, victory:

```
istanbul cover C:/dev/my_project/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha --
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this, may works for you. Script tag in your package.json

```
"cover" : "NODE_ENV=test babel-node ./node_modules/babel-istanbul/lib/cli cover --dir ./coverage _mocha -- -R spec --ui bdd ./test/setup.js ./test --recursive"
```

**setup.js** will be your setup javascript

**./test** will be the folder where all your tests sits.

packages need to install:

- babel-istanbul
- babel-node
- mocha

This works for me :) (npm run cover)

---

Note: 
if on **windows**: remove **NODE_ENV=test**, and may need to make the **_mocha** full path to your node module folder

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting up a new project and trying to get istanbul to work, ensure that you have a least one test file that references at least one of the project files for istanbul to reference for its coverage report.

```
"istanbul": "0.4.4",
   "mocha": "3.0.0"
```

In my case, I was setting up a new project and getting the first `index.js` and `test/index.spec.js` files prepped.  When I tried to run:

```
"test": "istanbul cover --report html node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- test/**/*.js --ui bdd -R spec"
```

I got an output from mocha of all unit tests passing (which there were no tests written yet so all 0 of them passed) but I then received this error after that:

> No coverage information was collected, exit without writing coverage information

The issue turned out to be that I had not yet added a `require` for the `index.js` file in the `test/index.spec.js` file yet.  Istanbul had no files to reference from the test files to check for coverage information.

If it's a pathing issue to _mocha referenced in the npm script, there will be an additional *"SyntaxError:"* message that follows the *"No coverage information was collected"* message.